# Passing BCrypt hash to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I want to encypt a password using BCrypt and then pass it to another function to store it in DB. The problem is that I can't pass it successfuly. I receive an error: "ReferenceError: hashedPass is not defined" on write-to-db.js:18

This part of code encrypts and has to send the hash to "write.registerUser()"

```html
  bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt){
   bcrypt.hash(query.password, salt, function(err, hashedPass){
    console.log(hashedPass); //I get the hash printed here with no problems
    write.registerUser(function(data, fName, lName, email, role, date, hashedPass){
     return();
    });
   });
  });
```

That is write-to-db.js where I try to save to DB but fail:

```html
 registerUser(Callback) {
  var sql = "INSERT INTO users_data (first_name, last_name, email, role, registration_date, active, password) VALUES ('"+fName+"', '"+lName+"', '"+email+"', '"+role+"', '"+date+"', '"+1+"', '"+hashedPass+"')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   Callback(result);
  });
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `registerUser(Callback) {` --- this function declaration only has a single `Callback` argument. So `hashedPass` is totally not defined there.

Comment: Where are `first_name, last-name`, etc coming from in the registerUser function? Those don't match the params being passed in from hash function. If they are though, are those defined?

Comment: how about using `next()` `

Comment: Everyting works fine except the hash part. All the other params are fine. If i pass the password as is, and deleting the hashing function all the details get inserted successfuly

Comment: @zerkms so what shoud it look like? And as I said, the console.log(hashedPass) just 1 line above the write.registerUser prints the hashed value. Thats why I dont get why it doesn't pas it to the function too.

Comment: Your registerUser function doesn't share the same context as the function from which it is called. So it doesn't have access to hashedPass. That's why you need to rewrite your registerUser function to accept the parameters that it needs to complete the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your registerUser function to:

```
registerUser(params, callback) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO users_data (first_name, last_name, email, role, registration_date, active, password) VALUES ('"+params.fName+"', '"+params.lName+"', '"+params.email+"', '"+params.role+"', '"+params.date+"', '"+1+"', '"+params.hashedPass+"')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

and change your hash generating code to:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt){
        bcrypt.hash(query.password, salt, function(err, hashedPass){
            console.log(hashedPass); //I get the hash printed here with no problems
            write.registerUser({
                data, 
                fName, 
                lName, 
                email, 
                role, 
                date, 
                hashedPass
            }, function(results){
                console.log(results)
                return();
            });
        });
    });
```

WARNING: this SQL query is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION. You would be wise to use prepared statements or an ORM.

Comment: Thank you guys! The corrections offered by @Porlune worked.
And sure I'll fix the vulnerablity to injections.